Reconnecting bluetooth headphones freezes ubuntu after a long time away
Since a few months Ubuntu freezes if I try to re-connect my headphones.
It happens as follows:

I connect my headphones using gnome settings, without issue (see image below)



I disconnect my headphones by either disabling bluetooth itself or just disconnecting the headphones. Still no issue.

Then I connect my headphones to an Android device, typically because I want to bring my headphones outside of my house. I lock my Ubuntu device in the meantime.

Usually later on the same day, I come back home and I want to reconnect my headphones to the original ubuntu device. So I disconnect my headphones from my android device.

I try to reconnect my headphones using gnome settings again (see image below). At this point Ubuntu crashes.



To debug my issue, I tried to just connect and disconnect the headphones rapidly in succession. However this does not reproduce my issue. I think this may only happen if I connect to a different device in between. I've also looked at the logs, but I don't see a clear solution to my problem. (I've added some logs that occur around the freezing below)
I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.06.LTS, gnome version 3.36.8, and the X11 windowing system.
The output of uname -a is:
uname -a
Linux m 5.15.0-10107-tuxedo #117~20.04.1tux2 SMP Tue May 7 10:13:33 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

And these are the journalctl log:
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m NetworkManager[1919]: <info>  [1716381244.3204] agent-manager: agent[322cfa8a5f123d58,:1.87/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: loading user theme: /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:04 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:05 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:05 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:05 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
May 22 14:34:05 m gnome-shell[5292]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
May 22 14:34:06 m gnome-shell[5292]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10558: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
May 22 14:34:15 m bluetoothd[1911]: Unable to get Headset Voice gateway SDP record: Host is down
May 22 14:34:17 m systemd[1]: fprintd.service: Succeeded.
May 22 14:34:35 m blueman-tray[5765]: Unable to connect to the Notification Watcher: Timeout was reached
May 22 14:34:40 m blueman-tray[5765]: Unable to connect to the Notification Watcher: Timeout was reached
...
May 22 14:34:44 m /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[3615]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:86
...
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[3407]: Stopped target Current graphical user session.
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[3407]: unicast-local-avahi.path: Succeeded.
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m gnome-control-c[5518]: g_variant_get_boolean: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_BOOLEAN)' failed
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[1]: Stopping Accounts Service...
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[1]: Stopping ACPI event daemon...
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[1]: Stopping Save/Restore Sound Card State...
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[1]: Stopping Availability of block devices...
May 22 14:35:45 m bluetoothd[1911]: Terminating
May 22 14:35:45 m systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth service...

Thank you in advance for your help.
